# Headers replace items in RecyclerView with multiple view type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView the adapter with multiple view type in which are initialized:

1. First Header on 0 position
2. ArrayList items on 1 position
3. Second Header on 8 position

My problem - headers replace items on the specified positions, but aren't located irrespective of items.

Adapter:

```
public MainAdapter(ArrayList<Model> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        case TYPE_SECOND_HEADER:
            return TYPE_SECOND_HEADER;
        default:
            return TYPE_ITEMS;
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            ViewGroup baseVHV = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.utils_recyclerview_header_base, viewGroup, false);
            BaseHeaderViewHolder baseVH = new BaseHeaderViewHolder(this.context, baseVHV);
            return baseVH;
        case TYPE_ITEMS:
            ViewGroup baseVHV1 = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.utils_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
            BaseViewHolder baseVH1 = new BaseViewHolder(this.context, baseVHV1);
            return baseVH1;
        case TYPE_SECOND_HEADER:
            ViewGroup baseSVHV = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.utils_recyclerview_second_header_base, viewGroup, false);
            BaseSecondHeaderViewHolder baseSVH = new BaseSecondHeaderViewHolder(this.context, baseSVHV);
            return baseSVH;
        default:
            ViewGroup baseVHV2 = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.utils_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
            BaseViewHolder baseVH2 = new BaseViewHolder(this.context, baseVHV2);
            return baseVH2;
    }
}   

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            BaseHeaderViewHolder header = (BaseHeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
            header.initView("Test");
            break;
        case TYPE_ITEMS:
            BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder = (BaseViewHolder) viewHolder;
            baseViewHolder.initView(this.items.get(i));
            break;
        case TYPE_SECOND_HEADER:
            BaseSecondHeaderViewHolder header2 = (BaseSecondHeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
            header2.initView("Test");
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


}
```

I can't present in what a mistake. I hope for you, many thanks!

Comment: In getItemViewType() you should check against the required positions 0, 1, and 8 in cases, and not view types.

Comment: Can you write a small piece of a code?

Comment: Added as answer with code as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getItemViewType() you should check against the required positions 0, 1, and 8 in cases, and not view types.

```
@Override 
public int getItemViewType (int position) 
{ 
    switch (position) 
    {  
    case 0:
        return TYPE_HEADER; 

    case 8:
        return TYPE_SECOND_HEADER;

    default:
        return TYPE_ITEMS; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Really, it was necessary to make it only. Thanks, you've rescued my day!

Answer (score 0):

> My problem - headers replace items on the specified positions, but
>   aren't located irrespective of items.

This is happening because you are adding the headers as a separate item.
What you want to do is have a separate view in your viewholder just for the header. This way you can use the combination of both itemViewType and position to show header and the right views for a position in your onBindViewHolder. You can do something like below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder = (BaseViewHolder) viewHolder;
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            //Make your header view visible
            baseViewHolder.initHeader();
            break;        

        case TYPE_SECOND_HEADER:
            //Make your second header view visible
            baseViewHolder.initSecondHeader();
            break;

        case default:
            //hide both headers since the type is not header
            baseViewHolder.hideHeader();
            baseViewHolder.hideSecondHeader();
            break;

    }
    baseViewHolder.initView(this.items.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Strangely the fact that in other adapter similar realization works, but there header is part of ArrayList<items> . It isn't believed that I've spent for search of the solution of this problem the whole week.Can you write as an example a little code?

Comment: Thanks, but what code has to be for hideHeader () or showHeader () in HeaderViewHolder?

Comment: Change the visibility of header views to hidden

Comment: Thank you so much, but i want to use several viewholders in my adaper. I think that your idea is simple, but it's not a solution for me.